# How to write async await function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Hi I am trying to write Async await function but this is not working for some reason. Can someone please guide me what error am I doing in writing this. I have written the function below. Thanks!

```
async function hello(){
  for(let ind = 1; ind < 390; ind++){
    let urll = worksheet[`A${ind}`].v;
    await urlStatusCode(urll, (error, statusCode) => {
      if (error) {
        c1 = c1+1
        console.log(error)
        console.error('error ', c1)
        console.error(urll)
        console.error('hello')
      } else {
        console.log('without error', c , 'url is ', urll)
        c = c+1
        if (statusCode == 404){
            console.log('hello');
        }
      }
    })
  } 
}
```

Any help would mean a lot. Thanks!

Comment: `await` is used with functions that return promises. Functions that return promises don't usually take a callback function parameter. It's either promises or callbacks, not both.

Comment: This sounds very much like you want to [promisify](https://javascript.info/promisify) the `urlStatusCode()` function. Sound about right?

Comment: If you use promisify, then you probably also want to use something like [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)